# QT - Dibujar sobre QPainter o sobre QPixmap?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Estoy intentando generar unas graficas de gran tamaño con Qt utilizando QGraphicsItems. Ahora bien, la duda mia viene por el siguiente lado...tengo cerca de 10000 triangulos que dibujar para formar un "camino", que es lo mas conveniente y performante?, dibujar sobre el propio QPainter cada vez que agrega un punto/triangulo? o bien realizar el dibujo sobre un QPixmap y luego poner el QPixmap en el QPainter?. Pregunto esto porque leí algo que al dibujar en el QPixmap estoy utilizando la aceleracion de hardware...pero no sé si al dibujar sobre el propio QPainter tambien la utiliza o no. Disculpen que no ponga código porque es mas que nada una cuestion conceptual para conocer cual es mas performante. Si alguien se "enoja" por no tener código la pregunta, puedo agregar un ejemplo utilizando QPainter sin QPixmap. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo pones en un `QPainter`, los triángulos se recalcularán cada vez que haya que repintar la escena, mientras que si pintas en un `QPixmap`, el repintado simplemente impliciará volcar la imagen a la pantalla

¿Qué sale más a cuenta? Pues depende:

El repintado es una operación menos costosa que pintar los triángulos, sin embargo para que podamos volcar el `QPixmap` en pantalla antes hemos tenido que *pintar* la imagen... y el tiempo empleado en ello es equivalente al de pintar los triángulos en el `QPainter`.

Conclusión:

Si la imagen suele ser estática la mayor parte del tiempo sería recomendable intercalar el `QPixmap`. Ahora bien, si la imagen va a cambiar prácticamente en cada refresco, no vas a obtener ninguna ventaja con esta estrategia y obtendrás mejores tiempos usando el `QPainter`.

Ahora bien, yo aquí añadiría una tercera opción y es usar la tarjeta gráfica (opengl sobre Qt). Si el número de triángulos es lo suficientemente elevado es una opción a tener muy en cuenta.

Por otro lado, no hay que olvidar que una opción, por si sola, no será buena. Es necesario que la implementación de dicha solución sea adecuada para poder exprimir su potencial. Esto, aunque pueda parecer obvio, nunca está de más tenerlo en cuenta. En estos casos lo mejor es medir las diferentes soluciones para tener la certeza de elegir la opción que mejor se adapta a nuestras necesidades.

Comment: Excelente respuesta @eferion, la tercera opcion (Opengl) parece la mas adecuada, solo que no me siento comodo con opengl...por mas que leo no le puedo tomar la mano.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres https://learnopengl.com. Este tutorial es bastante completo y facil de seguir. Los tutoriales obsoletos y con errores abundan, lamentablemente